# Why Do I get a segmentation fault 11 using malloc for a struct?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm new to C and work myself throug the MIT Open Courseware for practical C programming ([MIT OCW Homepage](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-087-practical-programming-in-c-january-iap-2010/assignments/)) in order to learn some C basics.

In assignment 5 we are supposed to implement a small binary tree library for allocation, deallocation, display and traversal.

While testing the following implementation

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNodeStruct {
        int data ;
        struct TreeNodeStruct *left, *right ;
} ;

typedef struct TreeNodeStruct TreeNode ;

TreeNode* talloc(int data)
{

    /* variables */

    TreeNode *p ;

    /* logic */

        p = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNodeStruct)) ;
        p->data = data ;

    /* return */

    return p ;

}

TreeNode* addnode(TreeNode* root ,int data)
{

    /* logic */

        if(root == NULL) return talloc(data) ; // allocate node and return as new root
        else if(data < root->data) root->left = addnode(root->left, data) ;
        else root->right = addnode(root->right, data) ;

    /* return */

    return root ;

}
```

in a very simple test case

```
printf("\nProblem 5.2\n") ;

tree = talloc(0) ;

printf("talloc(0): %s\n", tree == NULL ? "failure" : "success") ;

for(int i1 = 0, i2 = 10; ++i1 < i2 ; ) addnode(tree, i1) ;
```

I run into a segmentation fault 11 error. Is this an artefact of my test case or an error in my implementation? If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. It will initialize the members of the node with zeros. And use `sizeof *p` instead of `sizeof(struct TreeNodeStruct)`. `sizeof` is compile-time.

Comment: Alright, simple problem, simple solution. Thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` doesn't initialize the members of the `struct`. Add code to do that.

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNodeStruct)) ;
p->data = data ;
p->left = NULL;
p->right = NULL;
```

You can also use `calloc` if you don't want to have those lines.

```
p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TreeNodeStruct)) ;
p->data = data ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `left` and `right` to `NULL` in `talloc()`. `addnode()` cannot identify non-existing subtree correctly.

You should note that `malloc()` does not initialize anything in the allocated memory space. To initialize it into `0` automatically, you should use `calloc()`.

```
p = calloc(1, sizeof(TreeNode));
```

Answer (score 2):

In `talloc` you need to set left and right to NULL.

When your code iterates through the binary tree, it will continue to call itself recursively until it finds NULL, which indicates you are on a "leaf". But since left and right contain garbage, it won't find NULL.

Comment: Ok, yeah i get it now. `left` and `right` weren't initialized. Why aren't they initialized to `0` though? Or, more to the point, why do they point to "garbage"?

Comment: @FK82 Because malloc does nothing but allocating a chunk of memory as fast as possible. It does not initialize the allocated memory to any known values. Unlike calloc, which is guaranteed to initialize the allocated memory to zero.